# Converting image type into WKT?

Tags: geometry, well-known-text

I’m working with a GIS that uses SQL Server as its DBMS. So I have to insert some data into a column called dbo.CidadesGeo, but before do that I have to understand how the geometry (geometria) column works. In addition, idcidade = idcity.

[image]

So, as you can see, the “geometria” column is set such as image type. When I selected all data I found something like that:

[image]

I’d like to convert this image type into WKT, then I could see how the coordinates looks like. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Do you know what format it's currently in? I couldn't find any file types that start with the decimal bytes 119, 0, 0, 0 as yours does.